# Javascript: Can set transition with querySelector

Tags: javascript

I am making a class and I have to use a querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName or getElementById but the way I make things disappear (setting the opacity to 0 with a transition the setting the display to none) isn't working the same. No animation is being made. Here is my code

```
makeReappear: function(animated = false, trigger = null, target = null)
    {
        var triggerProvided = false;
        var targetProvided = false;
        if (trigger != null && target != null && triggerProvided === false && targetProvided === false)
        {
            triggerProvided = true;
            targetProvided = true;
            if (triggerProvided && targetProvided)
            {
                var isAnimated = false;
                if (animated === false)
                {
                    if (document.querySelector(target).style.display === "none")
                    {
                        document.querySelector(target).style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        console.log("Cannot set display propery.");
                    }
                }
                else if (animated === true && isAnimated === false)
                {
                    isAnimated = true;
                    if (isAnimated)
                    {
                        if (document.querySelector(target).style.display === "none")
                        {
                            document.querySelector(target).style.transition = "all 2s";
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                document.querySelector(target).style.opacity = 100;
                            }, 1000);
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                document.querySelector(target).style.display = "block";
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        console.log("Could not determine if animated was set to true");
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log("Invalid target");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("No elements selected");
        }
    }
```

That is a small part of the class. The function I am having difficulty with. It wont set the opacity to 100 with the 2 second animation I set. Why is this? Yet when I make it disappear it works fine.

Comment: We don't have enough context to help you properly. Set up a working jsfiddle/codepen example that demonstrates your problem. Are you sure that `target` is a proper class selector? Also, opacity goes from 0 to 1. 100  is invalid - although I expect a browser might just treat it the same as 1.

Comment: There's some odd code there. In 3 different spots, you set variables to either `true` or `false`, and then check them in an `if` statement to see if they are the value you just set. Like... `isAnimated = true; if (isAnimated) {...`

Comment: It affects the correct element - e.g makes it visible again

Comment: They are Booleans...

Comment: If I don't set them I get an error that what I am trying to select is not defined or null. So I am using Booleans to force the browser to check for what element I put in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation won't work because you're toggling the display after setting the opacity.

If you set the display to block at the same time as setting the transition, and then modify the opacity in the timeout, it should work.

```
document.querySelector(target).style.transition = "all 2s";
document.querySelector(target).style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector(target).style.opacity = 1;
}, 1000);
```

assuming u have already set it's opacity to 0 prior

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector(target).style.opacity = 1;
       }, 1000);
       setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector(target).style.display = "block";
       }, 2000);

Comment: I have the first setTimeout changing the opacity. Then the second one changing display it still wont display an animation.

Comment: Please re-read my post. That is the problem... When the opacity is being set, the button is hidden. the display needs to be changed before setting the opacity to 1.

Comment: Oh... I skimmed the code. Sorry, I assumed you were pointing out something else.

Comment: Worked like a charm.